# BouncyCastle required in Java 8 121?

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle

So we recently updated Java on our Centos servers to `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el7_3.x86_64/` from `java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.60-2.b27.el7_1.x86_64` and we ran into problems with communications and TLS encryption, etc. We discovered the solution to those issues being the `java.security` file was not being overwritten with the new one (as we have specified BouncyCastleProvider in the file). Once we moved the `java.security.rmpnew` into place as `java.security`, our communication problems went away.

We did NOT update the new `java.security` file with the `BouncyCastleProvider`, however, yet the encryption in our application, which uses the `BouncyCastleProvider`, did NOT break. We even removed the `bcprov-*.jar` from the `jre/lib/ext` directory, restarted tomcat, rebooted the entire server, and STILL it works.  I have checked the release notes and not found anything mentioning it. I worry that these changes will eventually break and our encryption will start to fail. Yet it is working WITHOUT and `BouncyCastleProvider` on the server.I have checked the release notes and not found anything mentioning it. I worry that these changes will eventually break and our encryption will start to fail. Yet it is working WITHOUT and `BouncyCastleProvider` on the server.

TLDR; my question is is BouncyCastle now included in Java8? We have removed the provider from java.security and the bcprov.jar from the /ext directory and it is still working. We are using `jasypt v1.9.2` for the encryption.

`pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
  <version>1.52</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Code:

```
StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
String algorithm = "PBEWITHSHA256AND256BITAES-CBC-BC";
String providerName = "BC";

encryptor.setAlgorithm(algorithm);
encryptor.setProviderName(providerName);

String encData = EMPTY_STRING;

try{
  encryptor.setPassword("myPassword");
  encData = encryptor.encrypt(dataToEncrypt);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. BouncyCastle isn't included in OpenJDK 8, or prior versions.

Most likely, the library is bundled in the web applications or is present in one of Tomcat's extension libraries.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It must have been cached somewhere, as after a couple weeks, we started getting failures for it missing. I don't know where it was cached as I cleaned out the cache directory, restarted everything, etc. but it seems we still need it. Which is a relief as I was wondering HOW we were encrypting without it. Thanks again